# What kind of functions satisfy $y'(x) =x'(y)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What kind of functions satisfy the property $y'(x) =x'(y)$ ? I don't know if it makes sense.

For example, for $x^2+y^2=1$,
$$\begin{align}y'(x)& = \frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\
x'(y) & = \frac{-y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\end{align}$$

What I am trying to ask is that what kind of other functions are symmetric like this, as it only changes the $x$ and $y$ between $\frac{dx}{dy}$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: Confusing. That said, the original expression is symmetric in $x$ and $y$ so any conclusions you draw will be symmetric too. So that symmetry can produce other examples. When asking here, use mathjax to write mathematics: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: First, that's an equation not a function.

But if you're asking for others like it, I believe $|x|+|y|=a^2$ for some integer $a$ should work.

Comment: I'd guess that any equation with both $x$ and $y$ axis symmetry should suffice.

Comment: It might be interesting to investigate which non-symmetric functions (if any) have symmetric derivatives in this manner.

Comment: I don't think this question is correctly phrased. It seems you are looking for _symmetric_ expressions, instead of _equal_ expressions. Consider your example; in fact $y'(x) = -x \big/ \sqrt{1-x^2} \neq -y \big/ \sqrt{1-y^2} = x'(y)$. As it is right now, $y'(x)=x'(y)$ is actually $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dx}{dy} \iff \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2=1$ and the solutions are $y=\pm x +c$.

Answer (score 3):

If $f(x,y) = f(y,x)$ then when you find the implicit derivatives of $y$ with respect to $x$ and vice versa for the "curve"
$$
f(x,y) = c
$$
(where $c$ is some constant)
the derivatives will be symmetric in the way you ask about.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $y=f(x)$ where $f$ is invertible so that $x=f^{-1}(y).$ As I understand your question you ask for $f$ such that $f'=(f^{-1})'.$ This is equivalent to having $f(t) = f^{-1}(t) + c$ for some constant $c.$ Setting $t=f(x)$ then gives the functional equation
$$f(f(x)) = f^{-1}(f(x))+c = x+c.$$

For the case $c=0$ we have a lot of examples:

- $f(x)=x$
- $f(x)=1/x$
- $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

For the case $c\neq0$ I right now only see one solution:

- $f(x)=x+\frac12 c$

I'm sure that others will find more solutions.